# Why the background colour blinks instead of smooth changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

In this little code I am trying to change the colour of body background smoothly, for the first test it did the best job for one time,in other test the colour changed with blinking.
Who knows the reason ?pleas solve it for me?
This was against my goal of this program but I found that this is the real colour dancing.:D

```html
<html>
<body>
 Interval:<input type="number" id="interval" min="0" placeholder="millisecond" value="10" step="10"/>
 Start Point Color: 
  R<input type="number" id="redStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="ed" value="0"/>
  G<input type="number" id="greenStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="reen" value="0"/> 
  B<input type="number" id="blueStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="lue" value="0"/>
 Dancing Color:
  R:<input type="checkbox" id="redDance" checked="true"/>
  G:<input type="checkbox" id="greenDance"/>  
  B:<input type="checkbox" id="blueDance"/>
  <button type="button" id="dance">Dance</button>
  <button type="button" id="stopDance">Stop Dance</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //event for click on dance button
    document.getElementById('dance').onclick = Dancer;
 document.getElementById('stopDance').onclick = stopDancer;

 // this is the dancer function that is responsible for the background color dancing
 function Dancer(){
  var body_color  = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  var interval_ms = document.getElementById('interval').value;
  var is_red = document.getElementById('redDance').checked;
  var is_green = document.getElementById('greenDance').checked;
  var is_blue = document.getElementById('blueDance').checked;
  var red = document.getElementById('redStart').value;
  var green = document.getElementById('greenStart').value;
  var blue = document.getElementById('blueStart').value;
  //document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
     document.dancing = setInterval(function(){
   if (is_red && red < 255){
    red++;
    document.getElementById('redStart').value = red;
   }
   if(is_green && green < 255){
    green++;
    document.getElementById('greenStart').value = green;
   }
   if(is_blue && blue < 255){
    blue++;
    document.getElementById('blueStart').value = blue;
   }
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
  },interval_ms
  );
 }
 
 //this is the dancer stop function
 function stopDancer(){
  clearInterval(document.dancing);
 }
  
 </script>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you need to clear the interval before setting another one.

Comment: I did but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interval is still running when you initiate `Dancer()` again and must be cleared. I added `else` statements for when the color is complete and an `if` statement for when all colors are complete that clears the interval. I also expanded your code with `else if` statements to count down the colors when unchecked.

```js
//event for click on dance button
document.getElementById('dance').onclick = Dancer;
document.getElementById('stopDance').onclick = stopDancer;

// this is the dancer function that is responsible for the background color dancing
function Dancer(){
  clearInterval(document.dancing);
  var body_color  = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  var interval_ms = document.getElementById('interval').value;
  var is_red = document.getElementById('redDance').checked;
  var is_green = document.getElementById('greenDance').checked;
  var is_blue = document.getElementById('blueDance').checked;
  var red = document.getElementById('redStart').value;
  var green = document.getElementById('greenStart').value;
  var blue = document.getElementById('blueStart').value;
  var redDone = false;
  var greenDone = false;
  var blueDone = false;
  document.dancing = setInterval(function(){
    if (is_red && red < 255){
      red++;
      document.getElementById('redStart').value = red;
    }
    else if (!is_red && red > 0){
      red--;
      document.getElementById('redStart').value = red;
    }
    else {
      redDone = true;
    }
    if(is_green && green < 255){
      green++;
      document.getElementById('greenStart').value = green;
    }
    else if(!is_green && green > 0){
      green--;
      document.getElementById('greenStart').value = green;
    }
    else {
      greenDone = true;
    }
    if(is_blue && blue < 255){
      blue++;
      document.getElementById('blueStart').value = blue;
    }
    else if(!is_blue && blue > 0){
      blue--;
      document.getElementById('blueStart').value = blue;
    }
    else {
      blueDone = true;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
    if(redDone && greenDone && blueDone){
      clearInterval(document.dancing);
    }
  },interval_ms
                                );
}

//this is the dancer stop function
function stopDancer(){
  clearInterval(document.dancing);
}
```

```html
Interval:<input type="number" id="interval" min="0" placeholder="millisecond" value="10" step="10"/>
Start Point Color: 
R<input type="number" id="redStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="ed" value="0"/>
G<input type="number" id="greenStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="reen" value="0"/> 
B<input type="number" id="blueStart" min="0" max="255" placeholder="lue" value="0"/>
Dancing Color:
R:<input type="checkbox" id="redDance" checked="true"/>
G:<input type="checkbox" id="greenDance"/>  
B:<input type="checkbox" id="blueDance"/>
<button type="button" id="dance">Dance</button>
<button type="button" id="stopDance">Stop Dance</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code that makes this little a bit bigger and useful

Answer (score 2):

Try this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anqpcjf7/).

I simply added a `clearInterval` at the beginning of your function. Now it doesn't blink. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: While your solution is simple best practice would be to clear the interval when the desired function is complete otherwise the interval is still running despite performing no useful function.

Comment: Thanks for your best answer Chris.